# Project Clean yields app failure

Tags: android

I just did a clean from ADT on a correctly working app and now it crashes. Here's what I know...

Here is main app...

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private GolferDBManager mydManager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Go get the Known Golfers
    mydManager = new GolferDBManager(this);
    mydManager.openReadable();
    mydManager.retrieveGolfers();
    mydManager.close();

}
```

and here is the GolferDBManager class:

```
public class GolferDBManager {
public static final String DB_NAME = "golfgames";
public static final String DB_TABLE = "golfers";
public static final int DB_VERSION = 1;
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DB_TABLE + " (index INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, golfer_name TEXT, golfer_init TEXT, usga_index DOUBLE);";
private SQLHelper helper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Context context;


public GolferDBManager(Context c){
    this.context = c;
    helper=new SQLHelper(c);
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
}
public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public SQLHelper(Context c){
        super(c, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }
```

It crashes on the

```
    this.db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
```

line of the

```
        mydManager = new GolferDBManager(this);
```

2 lines into the main app.

Did cleaning screw up the db?

Here's the debug stack

```
Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception RuntimeException))  
<VM does not provide monitor information>   
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2211    
ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 2261 
ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread, ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 141    
ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(Message) line: 1256  
ActivityThread$H(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 99 
Looper.loop() line: 137 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 5103    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 525  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 737  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 553 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Logcat says:

```
11-09 16:19:54.386: E/SQLiteLog(1184): (1) near "index": syntax error
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi..Can u please paste the stack trace so that we can help you out.

Comment: Just added debug stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using *index* as a field name when defining the fields of the database in the

```
CREATE_TABLE= ...
```

. Not sure why it was working for a time - it never should have. But changing it to another name fixed the problem.

Thanks for looking.

ddk

Comment: index is a keyword in sqlite and hence we cannot use it.http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html